# How to smooth curves line graph in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced a line graph using ggplot. But its edges are not smooth. How can I do that?

[image]

I tried using `geom_smooth()` and `stat_summary()` functions but I didn't get results. Its showing errors.

Here's my code for the line path:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,3,7,8,9,2),B=c(3,7,8,9,2,1,2,3,4,5,6),C=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2))
go <- ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=B, colour = C), pch = 17) +geom_point() 
go + geom_path(data = rbind(cbind(tail(df, -1), grp = 1:(nrow(df)-1)),  
                          cbind(head(df, -1), grp = 2:nrow(df)-1)),
             aes(group = interaction(grp)))
```

Comment: Show us which errors you get.

Comment: Where did you try to use `stat_smooth`? What exactly where the errors you got? Wouldn't just `ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=B), pch = 17) +geom_point() + stat_smooth()` work?

Comment: @MrFlick  But for the large dataset such as this one
`df <- data.frame(A=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,3,7,8,9,2),B=(3,7,8,9,2,1,2,3,4,5,6),C=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,‌​1,1,1,2,2))` 
its showing the linear regression smooth. I want the similar result as shown in example all the points are connected* but smoothly.

Comment: @Pascal
Here's the warning/error:
`geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is <1000, so using loess. Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.`

Comment: Show us which errors you get **inside** your post.

Comment: @Pascal I am not getting any error in my code that I have shown. But what I want is shown in this image posted (update).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple options, using smoothing splines and bezier curve

```
plot(df[,1:2])
xspline(df[,1:2], shape=-0.2, lwd=2)  # play with the shape parameter

library(bezier)
res <- bezier(seq(0, 1, len=100), df[,1:2], deg=nrow(df)-1)
points(res, type="l", col="green", lwd=2)
```

[image]

or in `ggplot2`

```
## Get points
ps <- data.frame(xspline(df[,1:2], shape=-0.2, lwd=2, draw=F))

## Add to your plot
go <- ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=B, colour = factor(C)), pch = 17) +
  geom_point(size=5) +
  geom_path(data=ps, aes(x, y), col=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately for ggplot2, xspline seems to fail when no plot.new has been called first, so you need to plot something first with base graphics, even though draw=FALSE is specified.

Comment: The issue identified by @ddiez can be sidestepped by merely adding `plot.new()` to the line before you call `xspline`.